# ActivityGroup call getParent()

Tags: android, activitygroup

I got stocked with this problem now for a while.

What I try in the program code:

text_notice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

```
            context = getParent();
            Log.i("", "Parent " + context.toString());

            edit_notice = new Dialog(context);
            edit_notice.setContentView(R.layout.edit_notice);
            edit_notice.setTitle(R.string.notice);

            final Button ok_button = (Button) edit_notice.findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
            final EditText notice_text = (EditText) edit_notice.findViewById(R.id.notice);

            ok_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    race.setNotice(notice_text.getText().toString());
                    raceDao = HelperSingleton.getInstance().getHelper().getRaceDaoException();
                    raceDao.update(race);
                    text_notice.setText(race.getNotice());
                    edit_notice.dismiss();
                } 
            });
            edit_notice.show();
            } 
    });
```

So basically adding a window to the ActivityGroup.

This code works fine if I go this path:
RowCoachActivity --> ResultsActivity --> ShowDetailsActivity

As soon as I try to get this path:
SettingsActivity --> RowCoachActivity --> ResultsActivity --> ShowDetailsActivity

The application crushes.

Could somebody please help me?

The call from Settings:
//ends the previous RowCoachActivity
RowCoachActivity.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

```
            Intent result_intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, RowCoachActivity.class);
            Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("RowCoachActivity", result_intent);
```

This is my LOG:

> 10-28 15:08:46.662: D/dalvikvm(611): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1157 objects / 81424 bytes in 44ms
>   10-28 15:08:53.262: I/dalvikvm(611): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>   10-28 15:08:53.282: I/dalvikvm(611): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   10-28 15:08:56.513: W/KeyCharacterMap(611): No keyboard for id 0
>   10-28 15:08:56.513: W/KeyCharacterMap(611): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>   10-28 15:08:59.063: I/(611): finished Activity RowCoach
>   10-28 15:09:00.963: D/dalvikvm(611): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2864 objects / 174056 bytes in 46ms
>   10-28 15:09:04.133: I/(611): Parent com.rowcoachultra.ResultsActivity@44f83e08
>   10-28 15:09:04.183: D/AndroidRuntime(611): Shutting down VM
>   10-28 15:09:04.183: W/dalvikvm(611): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44f68e40 is not valid; is your activity running?
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.rowcoachultra.ShowDetailsActivity$2.onClick(ShowDetailsActivity.java:111)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   10-28 15:09:04.192: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)